# What mechanism works to show component ID in chisel3 elaboration

Tags: chisel

Chisel throws an exception with an elaboration error message. The following is a result of my code as an example.

```
chisel3.core.Binding$ExpectedHardwareException: data to be connected 'chisel3.core.Bool@81' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type. Perhaps you forgot to wrap it in Wire(_) or IO(_)?
```

This exception message is interesting because `81` behind `chisel3.core.Bool@` looks like ID, not hashcode.
Indeed, Data type extends `HasId` trait which has `_id` field, and
`_id` field seems to generate a unique ID for each components.

I've thought Data type overrides `toString` to make string that has `type@ID`, but it does not override. That is why `$node` in below code should not be able to use ID.

```
throw Binding.ExpectedHardwareException(s"$prefix'$node' must be hardware, " +
            "not a bare Chisel type. Perhaps you forgot to wrap it in Wire(_) or IO(_)?")
```

Instead of `toString`, `toNamed` method exists in Data. However, this method seems to be called to generate a firrtl code, not to convert component into string.

Why can Data type show its ID?

If it is not ID, but exactly hashcode, this question is from my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala classes come with a default toString method that is of the form `className@hashCode`.

As you noted, the `chisel3.core.Bool@81` sure looks like it's using the `_id` rather than the `hashCode`. That's because in the most recently published version of Chisel (`3.1.6`), the hashcode was the id! You can see this if you inspect the source files at the tag for that version: https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/blob/dc4200f8b622e637ec170dc0728c7887a7dbc566/chiselFrontend/src/main/scala/chisel3/internal/Builder.scala#L81

This is no longer the case on `master` which probably the source of any confusion! As Chick noted, we have just changed the `.toString` method to be more informative than the default; expect more informative representations in `3.2.0`!

Comment: After reading your question, I noticed that chisel3 versions between I cloned from github and sbt on chisel-template downloads are probably different. As you noted, it is the root of confusion that reading `master` branch source code. Indeed, in `master` branch source code, `hashCode` method is still `override def hashCode: Int = super.hashCode()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look at [Chisel PR #985](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/pull/985). It changes the way that Data's toString method is implemented. I'm not sure if it answers your question directly but it's possible this will make the meaning and location of the error clearer. If not you should comment on it.